# R : create a zoo matrix from a csv file

Tags: r, csv, zoo

So I would like to create a zoo matrix from a Csv file but it doesn't work. My csv file is such as :

```
Date,Name
13/02/2015,Austria
07/08/2015,Austria
05/02/2016,Austria
22/07/2016,Austria
05/08/2016,Austria
03/02/2017,Austria
28/07/2017,Austria
26/01/2018,Austria
25/07/2011,Austria
28/10/2011,Austria
25/11/2011,Austria
20/01/2012,Austria
24/02/2012,Austria
26/04/2012,Austria
25/05/2012,Austria
11/07/2012,Austria
17/08/2012,Austria
09/11/2012,Austria
25/04/2013,Austria
29/07/2013,Austria
27/09/2013,Austria
30/09/2013,Austria
23/10/2013,Austria
16/01/2014,Austria
30/01/2014,Austria
21/02/2014,Austria
27/05/2014,Austria
30/07/2014,Austria
15/08/2014,Austria
```

I've followed many explanations from the forum but nothing works. So I've decided to follow these i[nstructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172226/reading-csv-in-r-with-zoo). Thus, I've "created" the following code :

```
> Lines <- "Date,Name
+ 13/02/2015,Austria
+ 07/08/2015,Austria
+ 05/02/2016,Austria
+ 22/07/2016,Austria
+ 05/08/2016,Austria
+ 03/02/2017,Austria
+ 28/07/2017,Austria
+ 26/01/2018,Austria
+ 25/07/2011,Austria
+ 28/10/2011,Austria
+ 25/11/2011,Austria
+ 20/01/2012,Austria
+ 24/02/2012,Austria
+ 26/04/2012,Austria
+ 25/05/2012,Austria
+ 11/07/2012,Austria
+ 17/08/2012,Austria
+ 09/11/2012,Austria
+ 25/04/2013,Austria
+ 29/07/2013,Austria
+ 27/09/2013,Austria
+ 30/09/2013,Austria
+ 23/10/2013,Austria
+ 16/01/2014,Austria
+ 30/01/2014,Austria
+ 21/02/2014,Austria
+ 27/05/2014,Austria
+ 30/07/2014,Austria
+ 15/08/2014,Austria
+ "
> library(zoo)
> read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = c("Date"), split = "Name", format = "d%m%Y", tz = "")
```

and I get :

```
Error in read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = c("Date"),  : 
  index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

What should I do, to resolve this ?

Thanks

Update:

Ok!

```
> df <- read_csv("austriatestfitch.csv", col_types = cols(When = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
+     read.zoo()
> auss1 = df
> str(auss1)
> aus2 = read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
> str(aus2)
library(eventstudy)
> eventstudy(firm.returns = auss1,
+            event.list = aus2,
+            event.window = 10,
+            is.levels =  FALSE,
+            type = "None",
+            to.remap = TRUE,
+            remap = "cumsum",
+            inference = TRUE,
+            inference.strategy = "bootstrap",
+            model.args = NULL)
```

and I obtain

```
Error in eventstudy(firm.returns = auss1, event.list = aus2, event.window = 10,  : 
  firm.returns should be a zoo series with at least one column. Use '[' with 'drop = FALSE'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your csv is called df.csv, try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df <- read_csv("df.csv", col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
      read.zoo()
```

Comment: It could be a BOM issue, or another invisible cahracter at the start of your first line. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933931/parser-does-not-match-column-name-in-csv-file-when-importing-using-readr-packag

Comment: Hi! No error message appears when I insert your code, but when I insert it in another code I got `df should be a zoo series with at least one column. Use '[' with 'drop = FALSE`

Comment: Hi. I am sorry but I do not understand your comment. What is in the new code you are talking about? How can we help?

Comment: Hi ! The thing is that I want to create a zoo matrix from my csv file, in order to use it for a specific function from a specific package. But when using the csv matrix created in the function i get the above error message

Comment: Then please post the code of your function, so we can test it.

Comment: Ok ! I've updated my question as the code was too long to be copied here :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the `read.zoo` statement:

- you can't split the data on `Name` as there are only two columns so that leaves no data left to split.  You can read in the Name column as data if you want and we do that below.
- there are no times so `Date` class would be sufficient.  That would avoid any complexities associated with time zones.  (You can use `POSIXct` if you really want but it is not recommended.)
- the `format=` argument is incorrectly specified.

Try this

```
read.csv.zoo(text = Lines, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

giving:

```
2011-07-25 2011-10-28 2011-11-25 2012-01-20 2012-02-24 2012-04-26 2012-05-25 
   Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria 
2012-07-11 2012-08-17 2012-11-09 2013-04-25 2013-07-29 2013-09-27 2013-09-30 
   Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria 
2013-10-23 2014-01-16 2014-01-30 2014-02-21 2014-05-27 2014-07-30 2014-08-15 
   Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria 
2015-02-13 2015-08-07 2016-02-05 2016-07-22 2016-08-05 2017-02-03 2017-07-28 
   Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria    Austria 
2018-01-26 
   Austria
```

We could add a column of 1's, say, to use as data if you really do want to split by `Name`:

```
DF <- read.csv(text = lines, as.is = TRUE)
DF$data <- 1
read.zoo(DF, format = "%d/%m/%Y", split = "Name")
```

Comment: This does not give an error when applied to the data in the question.  It gives the output shown.  If what you mean is you are trying it on data which differs in a way that you haven't explained then you will need to determine what the difference is.